# Validate a JWT from another C# ASP.NET Core 3.1 API that consumes it

Tags: security, jwt, asp.net-core-3.1, bearer-token

So I am getting a JWT from a web call that comes from Service A to secure Service B with the same token.  Unfortunately it uses a third party library so I don't know the exact key it issues but I can see it's payload just fine.  Is there a way I can make my service know the token is okay somehow?  I tried this in Startup.ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ")?.Last() ?? string.Empty;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                            context.Token = accessToken;

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Now this gets the JWT I expect and in a test case let's say this:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0LmNvbSJ9.XzkQ9hQ0JyhQDpFZ00Ukc_5ickUmjxVUBvlMrcEeycw

[image]

There is nothing wrong here and the 'context.Token' is getting set, but when I do this:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class JobsUpdateController : ControllerBase
```

I get a 401 no matter what when using the '[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes="Bearer")]'.  Is there anyway I can do a custom authorize?  Else I was thinking of doing some long form of setting my own authentication method and maybe making a custom attribute.  But I was hoping I could just get the startup working for this if I know the 'issuer' and several other keys in the payload of what I expect.

Comment: Why doesn't it have `exp` expiration time claim? You might have to disable lifetime validation (or other parameters) in `options.TokenValidationParameters`. It would **not** be as secure, if at all, given you don't have a public key to validate the signature.

Comment: @abdusco Oh it does, ultimately I just want to start small and get one thing working at a time with the smallest example possible.  Ultimate I do want to validate the exp, audience, and key as well but I just want to build it one at a time to ensure it's working on the overall [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")] on the Controller.

Comment: Why do you need to hook into OnMessageReceived event? ASP.NET Core extracts the token itself. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c18a43767ccbb57e0d47780afbee27a9e69b8dd8/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L73-L84

Comment: Don't know, I saw it on a tutorial.  Thus far nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure JWT validation in `options.TokenValidationParameters`.

This is **NOT** secure, and you're basically allowing pretty much any token. But regardless, here it is:

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(
        options => {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true, // `iss` claim
                ValidIssuers = new []{"https://localhost:1234"},
                ValidateAudience = false, // `aud` claim
                ValidateLifetime = false, // `exp`, `nbf` claims
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false, // signature
                SignatureValidator = (token, parameters) => new JwtSecurityToken(token), // don't validate signature
            };
        });
```

Comment: It looks like it should work but I still get a 401.  Maybe I am doing something wrong on the controller attribute?  https://imgur.com/a/pD4P8OO

Comment: The return header says: 'Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"'

Comment: Try adding a dummy `SignatureValidator`. See my answer

Comment: Yeah still not working whenever I post in at the top of the controller: [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")].  Do I need some other scheme?

Comment: @djangojazz Just tried, my code works with the token you posted when I add `SignatureValidator`. I can read claims just fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXWV6.png. This is the configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F6Ze.png

Comment: Alright your answer is right.  The problem is I was attempting this was an 'id_token' for a potential setup but it's not working.  It's probably for the best as this is not secure without the signing key.  I wanted this only interum till we got a better SSO system in place but the library has some encryption overtop a JWT and I was thinking I could use the identity key.  I just don't know security well enough to even know where I need to start.  But your answer is right with what I gave you, just doesn't work for my actual JWT, only a fake one.